# Simple example of use of __setstate__ and __getstate__

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, magic-methods

I don't know what the `__setstate__` and  `__getstate__` methods do, so help me with a simple example.

Comment: The docs aren't very good on this point anyway.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Here's a very simple example for Python that should supplement the [pickle docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocol).

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, val=2):
     self.val = val
  def __getstate__(self):
     print("I'm being pickled")
     self.val *= 2
     return self.__dict__
  def __setstate__(self, d):
     print("I'm being unpickled with these values: " + repr(d))
     self.__dict__ = d
     self.val *= 3

import pickle
f = Foo()
f_data = pickle.dumps(f)
f_new = pickle.loads(f_data)
```

Output:

```
I'm being pickled
I'm being unpickled with these values: {'val': 4}
```

Comment: To supplement this answer it prints "I'm being pickled", then "I'm being unpickled with these values: {'val': 4}", and f_new.val is 12.

Comment: While this is just a demonstration, it's still a bad idea to demonstrate something that shouldn't be done in real-world code. Namely mutating the object while it's undergoing pickling. Getting data from the object during `__getstate__` and doing shenanigans with that (and only that) without mutating the original object would be fine but that's not what's happening here.

Answer (score 73):

**Minimal example**

Whatever comes out of `getstate`, goes into `setstate`. It does not need to be a dict.

Whatever comes out of `getstate` must be pickeable, e.g. made up of basic built-ins like `int`, `str`, `list`.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.i
    def __setstate__(self, i):
        self.i = i
import pickle
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1), -1)).i == 1
```

**Default `__setstate__`**

The default `__setstate__` takes a `dict`.

`self.__dict__` is a good choice as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939384/895245 , but we can construct one ourselves to better see what is going on:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'i': self.i}
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1), -1)).i == 1
```

**Default `__getstate__`**

Analogous to `__setstate__`.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.i = d['i']
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1), -1)).i == 1
```

**`__slots__` objects don't have `__dict__`**

If the object has `__slots__`, then it does not have `__dict__`

If you are going to implement both `get` and `setstate`, the default-ish way is:

```
class C(object):
    __slots__ = 'i'
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __getstate__(self):
        return { slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__ }
    def __setstate__(self, d):
        for slot in d:
            setattr(self, slot, d[slot])
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1), -1)).i == 1
```

**`__slots__` default get and set expects a tuple**

If you want to reuse the default `__getstate__` or `__setstate__`, you will have to pass tuples around as:

```
class C(object):
    __slots__ = 'i'
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (None, { slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__ })
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1), -1)).i == 1
```

I'm not sure what this is for.

**Inheritance**

First see that pickling works by default:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
class D(C):
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        super(D, self).__init__(i)
        self.j = j
d = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(D(1, 2), -1))
assert d.i == 1
assert d.j == 2
```

**Inheritance custom `__getstate__`**

Without `__slots__` it is easy, since the `__dict__` for `D` contains the `__dict__` for `C`, so we don't need to touch `C` at all:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
class D(C):
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        super(D, self).__init__(i)
        self.j = j
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__
    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d
d = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(D(1, 2), -1))
assert d.i == 1
assert d.j == 2
```

**Inheritance and `__slots__`**

With `__slots__`, we need to forward to the base class, and can pass tuples around:

```
class C(object):
    __slots__ = 'i'
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __getstate__(self):
        return { slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in C.__slots__ }
    def __setstate__(self, d):
        for slot in d:
            setattr(self, slot, d[slot])

class D(C):
    __slots__ = 'j'
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        super(D, self).__init__(i)
        self.j = j
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (
            C.__getstate__(self),
            { slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__ }
        )
    def __setstate__(self, ds):
        C.__setstate__(self, ds[0])
        d = ds[1]
        for slot in d:
            setattr(self, slot, d[slot])

d = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(D(1, 2), -1))
assert d.i == 1
assert d.j == 2
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to reuse the default `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` of the base: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/QkvOwa1-pHQ we are forced to define them.

Tested on Python 2.7.12. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/python-cheat/blob/master/pickle_cheat.py).

Answer (score 18):

These methods are used for controlling how objects are pickled and unpickled by the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocol) module.  This is usually handled automatically, so unless you need to override how a class is pickled or unpickled you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

A clarification to @BrainCore's answer. In practice, you probably won't want to modify `self` inside `__getstate__`. Instead construct a new object that will get pickled, leaving the original unchanged for further use. Here's what that would look like:

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x:int=2, y:int=3):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = x*y

    def __getstate__(self):
        # Create a copy of __dict__ to modify values and return;
        # you could also construct a new dict (or other object) manually
        out = self.__dict__.copy()
        out["x"] *= 3
        out["y"] *= 10
        # You can remove attributes, but note they will not get set with
        # some default value in __setstate__ automatically; you would need
        # to write a custom __setstate__ method yourself; this might be
        # useful if you have unpicklable objects that need removing, or perhaps
        # an external resource that can be reloaded in __setstate__ instead of
        # pickling inside the stream
        del out["z"]
        return out

    # The default __setstate__ will update Foo's __dict__;
    # so no need for a custom implementation here if __getstate__ returns a dict;
    # Be aware that __init__ is not called by default; Foo.__new__ gets called,
    # and the empty object is modified by __setstate__

f = Foo()
f_str = pickle.dumps(f)
f2 = pickle.loads(f_str)

print("Pre-pickle:", f.x, f.y, hasattr(f,"z"))
print("Post-pickle:", f2.x, f2.y, hasattr(f2,"z"))
```

Comment: Good explanation of the reason to remove some dictionary entries.