# python, using multiprocess.Pool to spawn several subprocess calls

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I've searched several related posts, but none explicitly answer my query. I'm trying to create a class that will use multiprocessing to distribute jobs to a machine. The 'jobs' are system calls using subprocess and I don't wish for the script to stay connected to the jobs once spawned. I've gotten everything to work using the Process class, but I would like to try the Pool class, and I'm having problems.

My code is here:
https://gist.github.com/2627589

The relevant methods are the run_queue method. You can see in the Test_pool class I overwrite the run_queue method of my Runner class. However, when I run this, I get an error:
PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.instancemethod failed

My goal is to be able to define a MAX_NUM_CORES that should be kept busy, and continually submit jobs as long as the jobs distributed are not using more than the maximum number of cores defined (e.g. MAX_NUM_CORES). Maybe I'm not using the right design pattern? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing pickling error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error)

Comment: You need to define a module level function that can be imported that handles some of your functionality.  It's a requirement of the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work, but I realize it is also not what I need. I'll revert to the Process class and utilize is_alive to keep track of how many children are spawned and running.