# IPython cluster and PicklingError

Tags: python, ipython, pickle, jupyter-notebook, zipline

my problem seem to be similar to [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error) however, while I think I am following the advised method, I still get a PicklingError.  When I run my process locally without sending to an IPython Cluster Engine the function works fine.

I am using zipline with IPyhon's notebook, so I first create a class based on zipline.TradingAlgorithm

Cell [ 1 ]

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
rc = Client()
lview = rc.load_balanced_view()
```

Cell [ 2 ]

```
%%px --local  # This insures that the Class and modules exist on each engine
import zipline as zpl
import numpy as np

class Agent(zpl.TradingAlgorithm):  # must define initialize and handle_data methods
    def initialize(self):
        self.valueHistory = None
        pass

    def handle_data(self, data):
        for security in data.keys():
            ## Just randomly buy/sell/hold for each security
            coinflip = np.random.random()
            if coinflip < .25:
                self.order(security,100)
            elif coinflip > .75:
                self.order(security,-100)
        pass
```

Cell [ 3 ]

```
from zipline.utils.factory import load_from_yahoo

start = '2013-04-01'
end   = '2013-06-01'
sidList = ['SPY','GOOG']
data = load_from_yahoo(stocks=sidList,start=start,end=end)

agentList = []
for i in range(3):
    agentList.append(Agent())

def testSystem(agent,data):
    results = agent.run(data)  #-- This is how the zipline based class is executed
    #-- next I'm just storing the final value of the test so I can plot later
    agent.valueHistory.append(results['portfolio_value'][len(results['portfolio_value'])-1])
    return agent

for i in range(10):
    tasks = []
    for agent in agentList:
        #agent = testSystem(agent,data)  ## On its own, this works!
        #-- To Test, uncomment the above line and comment out the next two 
        tasks.append(lview.apply_async(testSystem,agent,data))
    agentList = [ar.get() for ar in tasks]

for agent in agentList:
    plot(agent.valueHistory)
```

Here is the Error produced:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/serialize.pyc in serialize_object(obj, buffer_threshold, item_threshold)
    100         buffers.extend(_extract_buffers(cobj, buffer_threshold))
    101 
--> 102     buffers.insert(0, pickle.dumps(cobj,-1))
    103     return buffers
    104 
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

If I override the run() method from zipline.TradingAlgorithm with something like:

```
def run(self, data):
    return 1
```

Trying something like this...

```
def run(self, data):
    return zpl.TradingAlgorithm.run(self,data)
```

results in the same PicklingError.

then the passing off to the engines works, but obviously the guts of the test are not performed.  As run is a method internal to zipline.TradingAlgorithm and I don't know everything that it does, how would I make sure it is passed through?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the zipline TradingAlgorithm object is not pickleable after it has been run:

```
import zipline as zpl

class Agent(zpl.TradingAlgorithm):  # must define initialize and handle_data methods
    def handle_data(self, data):
        pass

agent = Agent()
pickle.dumps(agent)[:32] # ok

agent.run(data)
pickle.dumps(agent)[:32] # fails
```

But this suggests to me that you should be creating the Agents on the engines, and only passing data / results back and forth (ideally, not passing data across at all, or at most once).

Minimizing data transfers might look something like this:

define the class:

```
%%px
import zipline as zpl
import numpy as np

class Agent(zpl.TradingAlgorithm):  # must define initialize and handle_data methods
    def initialize(self):
        self.valueHistory = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        for security in data.keys():
            ## Just randomly buy/sell/hold for each security
            coinflip = np.random.random()
            if coinflip < .25:
                self.order(security,100)
            elif coinflip > .75:
                self.order(security,-100)
```

load the data

```
%%px
from zipline.utils.factory import load_from_yahoo

start = '2013-04-01'
end   = '2013-06-01'
sidList = ['SPY','GOOG']

data = load_from_yahoo(stocks=sidList,start=start,end=end)
agent = Agent()
```

and run the code:

```
def testSystem(agent, data):
    results = agent.run(data)  #-- This is how the zipline based class is executed
    #-- next I'm just storing the final value of the test so I can plot later
    agent.valueHistory.append(results['portfolio_value'][len(results['portfolio_value'])-1])

# create references to the remote agent / data objects
agent_ref = parallel.Reference('agent')
data_ref =  parallel.Reference('data')

tasks = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(len(rc)):
        tasks.append(lview.apply_async(testSystem, agent_ref, data_ref))
# wait for the tasks to complete
[ t.get() for t in tasks ]
```

And plot the results, never fetching the agents themselves

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for history in rc[:].apply_async(lambda : agent.valueHistory):
    plt.plot(history)
```

This is not quite the same code you shared - three agents bouncing back and forth on all your engines, whereas this has on agent per engine. I don't know enough about zipline to say whether that's useful to you or not.