# Access data between two threading processes

Tags: python, multithreading, process

We are trying to access data between two threads, but are unable to accomplish this. We are looking for an easy (and elegant) way.

This is our current code.
Goal: after the second thread/process is done, the `listHolder` in instance `B` must contain 2 items.

```
Class A:
   self.name = "MyNameIsBlah"

Class B:
   # Contains a list of A Objects. Is now empty.
   self.listHolder = []

   def add(self, obj):
      self.listHolder.append(obj)

   def remove(self, obj):
      self.listHolder.remove(obj)

def process(list):
    # Create our second instance of A in process/thread
    secondItem = A()
    # Add our new instance to the list, so that we can access it out of our process/thread.
    list.append(secondItem)

# Create new instance of B which is the manager. Our listHolder is empty here. 
manager = B()

# Create new instance of A which is our first item
firstItem = A()

# Add our first item to the manager. Our listHolder now contains one item now.
b.add(firstItem)

# Start a new seperate process.
p = Process(target=process, args=manager.listHolder)

# Now start the thread
p.start()

# We now want to access our second item here from the listHolder, which was initiated in the seperate process/thread.

print len(manager.listHolder) << 1
print manager.listHolder[1] << ERROR
```

- Expected output: 2 `A` instances in `listHolder`.
- Got output: 1 `A` instance in `listHolder`.

How can we access our objects in the manager with the use of a seperated process/threads, so they can run two functions simultaneously in a non-thread-blocking way.

Currently we are trying to accomplish this with processes, but if threads can accomplish this goal in a easier way, then its not a problem. Python 2.7 is used.

Update 1:

@James Mills replied with using ".join()". However, this will block the main thread until the second Process is done. I tried using this, but the Process which is used in this example **will never stop execution (while True)**. It will act as a timer, which **must** be able to **iterate to a list** and **remove objects from the list**.

Anyone has any suggestion how to accomplish this and fix the current cPickle error?

Comment: What about using [Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)?

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest using new-style classes by inheriting from `object`, e.g., `A(object)` and not using reserved keywords, like `list`, as variable names.

Comment: You can use the ``multiprocessing.Manager`` here to manage data and attributes across processes implicitly which in turn uses Queues.

Comment: @Midnighter not actual code, just mockup but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Trying suggested out, will post results

Comment: Note that there's a subtle bug in your program that will cause issues if you use `multiprocessing.Manager`. Right now, it's possible that your main module will complete prior to your subprocess calling `list.append(secondItem)`. So you may get an `IndexError` trying to access `manager.listHolder[1]`, because your subprocess hasn't appendedto `listHolder` yet. You can fix it by adding a call to `p.join()` after `p.start()`.

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror Be aware, you might run into race condition problems. After you call `p.start()` your next line is checkinglistHolder length. But it might happen, that you do this check sooner, than started process manages to complete the task running in another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest ways of [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) is to use the `multiprocessing.Manager` class to synchronize data between processes (*which interally uses a `Queue`*):

**Example:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d, l):
    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2
    d[0.25] = None
    l.reverse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    l = manager.list(range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(d, l))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print d
    print l
```

**Output:**

```
bash-4.3$ python -i foo.py 
{0.25: None, 1: '1', '2': 2}
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

*Note:* Please be careful with the types of obejcts ou are sharing and attaching to your `Process` classes as you may end up with issues with pickling. See: [Python multiprocessing pickling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error)

Comment: Renamed `listHolder` to `lHolder` as suggested, because of reserved keywords.We now have changed `class B` with the following: http://pastebin.com/CP6UP5DW
Which results into:
`cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Comment: I feel you should simplify your code a bit and get the simplest thing working first. Your pickling problem is a different problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error

Answer (score 2):

if James Mills answer doesn't work for you, here's a writeup of how to use queues to explicitly send data back and forth to a worker process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging, multiprocessing, sys


def myproc(arg):
    return arg*2

def worker(inqueue, outqueue):
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger.info('start')
    while True:
        job = inqueue.get()
        logger.info('got %s', job)
        outqueue.put( myproc(job) )

def beancounter(inqueue):
    while True:
        print 'done:', inqueue.get()

def main():
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(
            level=logging.INFO,
    )
    logger.info('setup')

    data_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for num in range(5):
        data_queue.put(num)

    worker_p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=worker, args=(data_queue, out_queue), 
        name='worker',
    )
    worker_p.start()

    bean_p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=beancounter, args=(out_queue,),
        name='beancounter',
        )
    bean_p.start()

    worker_p.join()
    bean_p.join()
    logger.info('done')


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

from: [Django multiprocessing and empty queue after put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833742/django-multiprocessing-and-empty-queue-after-put/23837340#23837340)

Another example of using multiprocessing Manager to handle the data is here:

http://johntellsall.blogspot.com/2014/05/code-multiprocessing-producerconsumer.html

Comment: The difference here is that using a ``Queue`` is more like synchronize messages between your processes rather than synchonzing state (*some objects*). :)