# Closing the multiprocessing after each parallel job

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool, emcee

I am using `multiprocessing` library of python and also `emcee` which also uses different threads to implement `MCMC`. The problem is that even when I `close` the `pool` still it seems python uses the processors and slows down the cores and I have no idea what is the efficient way to release the cores after the job is done. Could anybody give me an idea of what I should do?
**Update:**
My code has been already posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382111/using-multiprocessing-in-a-class)

Comment: When you say python still uses the processors and slows down the cores, what do you mean?  How are you testing this?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I use ubuntu and then when I run command `top`, I see that my job was not killed and still the cores are being used.

Comment: post your code to give us an idea of exactly how you're closing the pool, also provide more detail about how you're running int.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I posted the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing a `Pool` doesn't stop it from doing work, it [just prevents new work items from being added to it](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close):

> **close()**
>
> Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the
>   tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.

So if you have a lot of queued tasks, closing the `Pool` won't make any difference in resource usage - all the workers will keep consuming those queued tasks until they're gone. If you want to basically abort all the work items immediately, you have to use [`pool.terminate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.terminate):

> **terminate()**
>
> Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work. When the pool object is garbage collected `terminate()` will be called immediately.