# Multiprocessing with dictionary of generator objects, TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, generator

How can I use multiprocessing to create a dictionary with generator objects as values?

Here is my problem in greater detail, using basic examples:

I have a large dictionary of lists whereby I am applying functions to compute on the dictionary values using `ProcessPoolExecutor` in `concurrent.futures`. (Note I am using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, not threads---there is no GIL contention here.)

Here is an example dictionary of lists:

```
example_dict1 = {'key1':[367, 30, 847, 482, 887, 654, 347, 504, 413, 821],
    'key2':[754, 915, 622, 149, 279, 192, 312, 203, 742, 846], 
    'key3':[586, 521, 470, 476, 693, 426, 746, 733, 528, 565]}
```

This is a small example---in reality, it is a massive dictionary with millions of keys and lists with thousands of elements.

Originally, I was processing these value lists using a function which appends to an empty list, e.g.

```
import concurrent

def manipulate_values(dict_items):
    k, v = dict_items
    return_values = []   ## empty list
    for i in v :
        new_value = i ** 2 - 13      ## compute something; just an example
        return_values.append(new_value)  ## append to list
    return k, return_values

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        new_dict = dict(executor.map(manipulate_values, example_dict1.items()))
```

However, the resulting dictionary lists `return_values` are too large for memory. Because I cannot hold these massive lists in memory, I decided to try generator functions, i.e. create a dictionary of keys and generator objects:

```
## generator function
def compute_values(v):
    for i in v:
        yield i ** 2 - 13   ## using example above; could be any function call 

def manipulate_values_with_generator(dict_items):
    keys, value_lists = dict_items
    return keys, compute_values(value_lists)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        new_dict = dict(executor.map(manipulate_values_with_generator, example_dict1.items()))
```

In the actual "big data" dictionary, this will result in a pickling error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object
```

There are other questions on this subject, but I'm not sure how to fix my problem---packages such as `dill` and `pathos` do not work with generators.

[Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-multiprocessing-pool-map/7309686)

[Can't pickle Pyparsing expression with setParseAction() method. Needed for multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883574/cant-pickle-pyparsing-expression-with-setparseaction-method-needed-for-multi/27892382)

Naturally, perhaps there's another way to solve my fundamental problem, which is doing multiprocessing on a large dictionary of lists within memory or generators. Maybe another data structure would be useful here?

Comment: Even if this would work you would receive a dictionary with generators which would, when requested, do the calculation in `compute_values` in the main process. Where is the gain of multiprocessing here?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am missing something---why wouldn't multiprocessing speed up this process? I'm using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595399/how-to-parallelize-computation-on-big-data-dictionary-of-lists

Comment: The object which is returned by a generator function (e.g. `cv` in a `cv = compute_values(...)`) is an iterator consisting of the reference to the generator function and some state (execution position in the function and local variables content). When calling `next(cv)` or `for item in cv` the generator function is executed until next `yield` or end **in the process and thread where e.g. `next(cv)` was called**.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I still don't quite understand your point, I'm afraid. Let me step back: I first wanted to use a dictionary of lists, but that cannot fit into memory. So, I would like to use a dictionary of generator objects. The gain of multiprocessing is to create that dictionary, as the actual dictionary is very very large.

Comment: I thought the calculations in `compute_values` where the actual payload which should be distributed among processes. If it is instead the dictionary creation and maybe the calculation of the `v` arguments for the `compute_values` function (although it doesn't seem so from your code) you can return the `v` objects from subprocesses and wrap them in generators in main process.

Comment: @MichaelButscher "wrap them in generators in main process." How would I do this without a generator function?

Comment: In the shown code this would be (without multiprocessing) simply something like `for k, v in example_dict1.items(): example_dict1[k] = compute_values(v)`. This can't be distributed among subprocesses (and distribution wouldn't be useful in the simple example).

Comment: Ok, so I think I now understand you: yes, I think the gain of multiprocessing would be in `compute_values`. That would be the gain of multiprocessing. The big dictionary already exists, and multiprocessing would allow each of the big dictionary values to be processed with `compute_values`. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes. So basically you should go back to the first solution without generators and somehow subdivide the big dictionary into reasonably sized chunks and only run multiprocessing for one chunk at a time. Then you can, depending on the actual task, aggregate the result somehow in main thread to reduce size or store it on disk in a database or simple file. Then memory is free for the next chunk.

Comment: @MichaelButscher "first solution without generators and somehow subdivide the big dictionary into reasonably sized chunks and only run multiprocessing for one chunk at a time" So, I'm trying this now in tandem with this question. In order to do this correctly, I am still stuck at how to do this "aggregate the result somehow in main thread to reduce size or store it on disk in a database or simple file". What would be the best way to store these object on disk? If I pickle them, I still need to re-load them into memory.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do with the calculated results and if they e.g. can be processed independently or if you e.g. want to calculate sum or average or something over them (what I meant with aggregation). One way can be an sqlite database where you can access data items individually and have some aggregation functions.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, I'll try this. Aggregation will be difficult, I suspect.

Comment: You can use a multiprocessing queue and send a sentinel at the end, signaling it's over.