# How can I use python multiprocessing with generators?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, bigdata, generator

I would like to use multiprocessing in python with generator functions

Let's say I have a massive list of lists `big_list`, and I would like to use multiprocessing to compute values. If I use "traditional" functions which return values, this is straightforward:

```
import concurrent

def compute_function(list_of_lists):
    return_values = []   ## empty list
    for list in list_of_lists:
        new_value = compute_something(list)    ## compute something; just an example
        return_values.append(new_value)  ## append to list
    return return_values

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
        new_list = list(executor.map(compute_function, big_list))
```

However, using lists in this manner is too memory intensive. So I would like to use generator functions instead:

```
import concurrent

def generator_function(list_of_lists):
    for list in list_of_lists:
        new_value = compute_something(list)    ## compute something; just an example
        yield new_value

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
        new_list = list(executor.map(generator_function, big_list))
```

My problem is, you cannot pickle generators. There are some workarounds to this problem for other data structures, but not for generators I think.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? There might be a better way to improve performance.

Comment: @AMC I am trying to avoid large lists, as they cannot fit in memory. For more context, I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798407/multiprocessing-with-dictionary-of-generator-objects-typeerror-cannot-pickle

Comment: @AMC I would say that, the fundamental problem I'm dealing with is how to use multiprocessing and not explode in RAM. That's essentially my problem, and the data structure I currently have is a dictionary of lists---does this make sense?

Comment: It's still too memory intensive if you loop over the results as they are produced? Do you transform the results later in way which reduces memory consumption, is the rest of the program set up to work like that?

Comment: "It's still too memory intensive if you loop over the results as they are produced?" Wouldn't that be far slower than using multiprocessing?

Comment: Ah, sorry if my comment wasn't clear, what I had in mind was something like [`multiprocessing.imap_unordered()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered). On second thought: You could have your processes add the results of the expensive function to a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) with a small maximum size. Once the queue is full the processes will simply wait until they can add to it, during which time they aren't working, and therefore not increasing memory use.

Comment: In any case, we need far more information before we can safely make concrete statements about this.

Comment: @AMC I've tried to distill the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811456/how-to-scale-operations-with-a-massive-dictionary-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can do your enumeration one level deeper in `big_list` using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to iterate the sublists.

```
import concurrent
import itertools

def compute_function(item):
    return compute_something(item)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(compute_function,
            itertools.chain.from_iterable(big_list)):
        print(result)
```

Comment: I suspect this will be just as memory intensive as the first approach, and wouldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

generator are just a fancy loop that preserve the state, it similar to the iterator logic, it provide you with a `next`, `hasNext` and similar api, so your loop will ask that iterator for the next item (as long as it has next item)

the implantation of the generator is completely up to the developer, it can be implemented by

- loading all data to memory and traverse it with next, thus achieve no memory efficient, e.g `for i in [1,2,3,4]`
- read line by line of some file, e.g `for line in file`
- if the generation function is known, generate the next element based on the last generated element e.g as in `range(100)`
- and much more...

all have a common requirement, where the generator need to keep it's current state so it will know what to `yield` in the next state, thus makes it very much **stateful** which in turn makes it very bad choice to use in multi-processing...

you can approach this problem with a map-reduce similar logic and split the whole list to small sublists, pass those to the workers and join all their output to the final result

Comment: "generator are just a fancy loop that preserve the state, thus makes it very much stateful which in turn makes it very bad choice to use in multi-processing..." I don't understand this---could you explain a bit more?

Comment: edit my answer, can you give some more details about your use case so I could provide a solution to your problem as well...

Comment: Thanks for this help---I've tried to better explain the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811456/how-to-scale-operations-with-a-massive-dictionary-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @EB2127, still don't have sufficient information about the processing logic, and whether those `list of lists` are independent, my suggestion remains, try to use some **map-reduce** approach

Comment: I agree---the question is, how to do this in a scalable way, which also doesn't explode memory