# How to scale operations with a massive dictionary of lists in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, bigdata, dask

I'm dealing with a "big data" problem in python, and I am really struggling for scalable solutions.

The data structure I currently have is a massive dictionary of lists, with millions of keys and lists with millions of items. I need to do an operation on the items in the list. The problem is two-fold:

(1) How to do scalable operations on a data structure this size?

(2) How to do this with constraints of memory?

For some code, here's a very basic example of a dictionary of lists:

```
example_dict1 = {'key1':[367, 30, 847, 482, 887, 654, 347, 504, 413, 821],
    'key2':[754, 915, 622, 149, 279, 192, 312, 203, 742, 846], 
    'key3':[586, 521, 470, 476, 693, 426, 746, 733, 528, 565]}
```

For a simple operation on the elements, the normal approach would be to iterate through the dictionary:

```
new_dictionary = {}

for k, v in example_dict.items():
    new_list = []    
    for i in v:      ## iterate through dictionary lists
        i = compute_something(i) ## this is just an example, e.g. i**2 or i-13 would also work
        new_list.append(i)
    # now, create a new dictionary
    new_dictionary[k] = new_list
```

The problem is, this cannot work for a dictionary this size---I'm working on a sever with over 250GB of RAM, and it quickly becomes too large for memory. It's also too slow/not scalable, as that's a single iteration with one processor.

Are there scalable solutions to this problem?

Maybe it would work to somehow break up the dictionary, do the calculations with multiprocessing, and aggregate? Or is there a way to save this data to disk?

I'm at a loss for ideas...

Comment: did you have a look at `dask` and `dask.bag`?

Comment: @ArcoBast This looks promising...The dictionary was originally a pandas DataFrame with a column of lists.

Comment: In addition, you probably have to think about how to store the lists on disk to avoid running into memory constraints.

Comment: @ArcoBast It looks like this is correct. Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would need to know more about your workflow. To me, it looks like you would not need to have the full example_dict in memory, but only individual key / value pairs of it. Also, new_dictionary does not need to be in memory, you only need to write new_list to it. I would therefore suggest that you have a look at [chest](https://github.com/blaze/chest), which is a 'spil to disk' dictionary.

Comment: Another way would be to replace example_dict by a mapping from key to the path, where the data is stored. `v`is then read in from that file at the beginning of each iteration. `new_list' is saved to disk at the end of the iteration, while `new_dictionary`
 only stores the path.

Comment: @ArcoBast I'll look into chest---I should mention that, the dictionary was original a pandas dictionary. I've been trying to see whether dask would help in this case as well...

Comment: Dask is mainly a parallelization library. You can use the dask.delayed interface for all sorts of data. Whether that resolves your memory issue depends on how you use it. Bad: as endpoint of your computational graph you return new_dictionary. This would require that all data is in memory. Better: in your computational graph, you write data to disk and return a pointer to the data (this could be `new_dictionary' with paths as keys)