# python multiprocessing PicklingError

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to do a multi-purpose paraloop class to be able to run multiprocessor jobs easily. Basically a user must define every iteration step as def iteration(index) within a with statement as in the example herein

here's my implementation

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import types


class paraloop(object):
    def __init__(self, ncores, niterations):
        self.niterations = niterations
        self.ncores      = min(ncores, self.niterations)

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pool     = mp.Pool(processes = self.ncores)
        self.iterated = 0
        # create results dict
        self.result = {}
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print isinstance (iteration, types.MethodType)

        def ITER():
            self.iterated += 1
            self.result[self.iterated] = iteration(self.iterated)
            if self.iterated < self.niterations:
                self.pool.apply_async( ITER ).get()

        print isinstance (ITER, types.MethodType)
        # run iterations in parallel    
        [self.pool.apply_async( ITER ).get() for idx in xrange(self.ncores)]

# usage example
import numpy as np
ITERATIONS = 10
ARRAY = np.ones(1000000)

with paraloop(ncores=4, niterations=ITERATIONS) as p:
    def iteration(index):
        print 'this is an iteration %i'%index
        s = 0
        for n in ARRAY:
            s += n
        return s
```

the print statement are to make sure that I have picklable function and not methods.

```
>> False
>> False
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>   File "paraloop.py", line 48, in <module>
>>     def iteration(index):
>>   File "paraloop.py", line 29, in __exit__
>>     [self.pool.apply_async( ITER ).get() for idx in xrange(self.ncores)]
>>   File "c:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
>>     raise self._value
>> cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Any idea why I am having this error message ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8804830/190597

Answer (score 0):

As an arbitrary rule take into account that, if you can't import it then you can't pickle it, since `pickle` will try to do that before serializing. Just don't define the target function inside another function!