# Fixed parameter for Map() in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there anyway to user map on a list with one fixed parameter without a for loop? for example

```
def addx(x, y):
  return x + y

print map(addx, 10, [10,20])
```

output should be 20 and 30

Thanks

Comment: `map(lambda e: e+10, [10, 20])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lambda` anonymous-function creator to inline a new function with only one argument:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def addx(x,y):
...     return x+y
...
>>> map(lambda x: addx(x,10), [10, 20])
[20, 30]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying with lambdas as well, didn't succeed.

Answer (score 7):

[`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to the rescue:

```
from functools import partial

map(partial(addx, 10), [10, 20])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>>
>>> def addx(x, y):
...   return x + y
... 
>>> map(partial(addx, 10), [10, 20])
[20, 30]
```

Comment: what is the difference between this answer and the one marked correct? memory?

Comment: @HassamSheikh none really. `partial` is just a helper function to do partial application. But just creating something like `lambda x: add(x, 10)` is just doing the partial application manually

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehensions:

```
def addx(x, y):
    return x + y

print [addx(10, i) for i in [10,20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `repeat` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import repeat

def addx(x, y):
  return x + y

map(addx, repeat(10), [10,20])
```

---

Side note:
if you are using `Executor.map()` from `ProcessPoolExecutor`, it's likely to get into trouble with a lambda method, as the passed function to `map` should be a top-level module function to be picklable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805244/3366323