# Replace pickle with dill and pymongo call

Tags: parallel-processing, pymongo, pickle, dill

I finally understood example how to replace pickle with dill from the following discussion: [pickle-dill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error/24673524?noredirect=1#comment60839340_24673524).
For example, the following code worked for me

```
import os
import dill
import multiprocessing

def run_dill_encoded(what):
    fun, args = dill.loads(what)
    return fun(*args)

def apply_async(pool, fun, args):
    return pool.apply_async(run_dill_encoded, (dill.dumps((fun, args)),))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    results = [apply_async(pool, lambda x: x*x, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,7)]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
    print(output)
```

I tried to apply the same philosophy to pymongo. The following code

```
import os
import dill
import multiprocessing
import pymongo

def run_dill_encoded(what):
    fun, args = dill.loads(what)
    return fun(*args)


def apply_async(pool, fun, args):
    return pool.apply_async(run_dill_encoded, (dill.dumps((fun, args)),))


def write_to_db(value_to_insert):           
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',  27017)
    db = client['somedb']
    collection = db['somecollection']
    result = collection.insert_one({"filed1": value_to_insert})
    client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    results = [apply_async(pool, write_to_db, args=(x,)) for x in ['one', 'two', 'three']]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
    print(output)
```

produces error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\...\temp2.py", line 10, in run_dill_encoded
    return fun(*args)
  File "C:\...\temp2.py", line 21, in write_to_db
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',  27017)
NameError: name 'pymongo' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../temp2.py", line 32, in <module>
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
  File "C:/.../temp2.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'pymongo' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Hi, I 'm the `dill` author.  Looks like you don't define `pymongo` inside your function.  Try putting the `import pymongo` inside `write_to_db`.  The function will serialize much better (or at all, sometimes) if you make sure all variables used in the function are defined locally.

Comment: Also, there's an easier way to use `dill` in `multiprocessing`.  Try the `multiprocess` module -- it's `multiprocessing` but with `pickle` replaced by `dill`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, thank you very much! It worked. I am still working on compiling `multiprocess` for Python 3.x. By the way, it there analog of `apply_async` for threads?

Comment: Have a look at `from multiprocessing import dummy` and then `p = dummy.Pool()` and `p.apply_async`.  It's threads, but using the process API.

Comment: I am afraid if I use `p.apply_async` it will use wrong `apply_async`. I need to make sure that redefined `apply_async` is called. I am testing it right now.

Comment: all you need to do is pass in the correct pool to your function, in this case, it's `p = dummy.Pool()`.

Comment: Thank you again! It worked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109829/discussion-between-user1700890-and-mike-mckerns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to put an `import pymongo` inside the function `write_to_db`.  This is because when the function is serialized, it does not take along any of the global references with it when it is shipped to the other process space.