# Pickle error in python when using SKlearns Joblib.dump on a pipeline object

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, pickle

I have a keras model that I import into SKlearn using the kerasregressor wrapper, in SKlearn I add it to a pipeline along with a standard scalar preprocessing. Which I try to save with joblib.dump(model,'filename'). However I get a rather long pickling error and I have no idea why, any help would be much appreciated.

My code is :

```
def basic_sss_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(40, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(40, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    return model


seed=7
np.random.seed(seed)
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=basic_sss_model, 
epochs=250, batch_size=20, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(params,xsecs,test_size=0.3,random_state=seed,shuffle=True)
log = pipeline.fit(x_train,y_train)
ypred = pipeline.predict(x_test)
print ypred
print ypred.shape
print "-------------------------"
print "true values:"
print y_test
print y_test.shape
joblib.dump(pipeline,'test.sav')
print 'pipeline dumped'
model = joblib.load('test.sav')
print 'loaded dumped model'
ypred1 = model.predict(x_test)
print ypred1
```

and I get the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bruno/PycharmProjects/NN/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    pipeline_save(pipeline, 'test')
  File "/home/bruno/PycharmProjects/NN/methods.py", line 95, in pipeline_save
    joblib.dump(model, file_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 484, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 281, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: it's not found as __builtin__.module
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled ,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error

Comment: Can you add the code for creating `basic_sss_model` to reproduce the error? Also to note, you can use batch normalization in keras.

Comment: I would still be interested in why pickle fails but I suspect its something to do with not defining a function at the highest level.

Comment: I found a work around using keras functions, `model.to_json()` and `model.save_weights('filename')`.  So `f=pipeline.named_steps.mlp.model.to_json()` then save the json file f, and `pipeline.named_steps.mlp.save_weights(filename)`. as a h5file. https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: issues with the work around it only saves the keras nn, not any of the normalization so its predicted values are off.