# Playing sound and a program

Tags: python, python-2.7, winsound

What I want to do is get an audio file to play while a def (function) is running. 
I've looked it up and seen that threading works but it is wayyyy to complicated for me to work out. Is there a way you guys can explain it to me? I was using winsound to play the audio file, and SND_FILENAME.

Comment: Well you do need to use threading

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Thought so, but I have no idea how to use it and the online documents don't help much

Comment: Check this out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thanks! I still have no idea to do this with an audio file. This seems pretty advanced, and I'm only just starting out in python.

Comment: You said you were using winsound to play the audio file, so just plug in that code into the function below (play), and add your other function there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def play():
    #winsound stuff

def function():
    #functiony stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=play)
    d = Process(target=function)
    p.start()
    d.start()
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, I get the following error code:
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function play at 0x03FDEE70>: it's not found as __main__.play

Comment: Can you show what you put inside play (and if you included parameters)? And also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error (where they use pathos).

Comment: it's okay, I figured it out myself. Ended up using the module threading, and `p = threading.Thread(target=play)` which worked.

Comment: You sent me on the right track though, so I'll accept your answer.