# Jupyter notebook can't pickle while multiprocessing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle, datalore

I am trying to implement multiprocessing in Datalore however I can't understand why I get error while I am trying the standard example from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) .
Here is the example snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

And the error what I am getting is as follows:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x7fe4f81ef048>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
```

I don't know what is wrong because I do not use Pickle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seems similar to yours. It also uses multiprocessing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function

Comment: you are getting `pickle`ing error because `multiprocessing` uses it internally

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Python 3.7.1, macOS 10.14