# Map a pool function keeping one variable fixed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I want to create a pool over a function of several variables where one is held fixed. If I was using a basic map I would have something like:

```py
def test_map(a,b):
    return a+b
serial_map = map(lambda x: test_map(2,x), [1, 1, 3])
```

But this does not work for a pool map:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(4)
p.map(lambda x: test_map(2,x), [1, 1, 3])
```

I'm aware this causes a pickling error. My point is that I would like a workaround if it is possible. I know for regular maps the idiomatic way of handling this issue is with lambdas, I would like to know the pool.map way of handling this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function

Comment: ***"pool.map way of handling this problem."***: `p.map(test_map, ((2,x) for x in [1, 1, 3]))`

Comment: stovfl I will vote reopen the question. Please write this as the answer and I will accept. @Mad Physicist this question is *not* a duplicate as the answer needn't involve any pickling in the end as stovfl's answer has demonstrated.

Comment: @DanielMarchand. Agreed. I closed it because the answer to the other question would work, but this is more elegant. Keep in mind that this *does* involve pickling, and the fact that your function is top-level is the *only* reason this works.

Comment: Did you try `from functools import partial` and `p.map(partial(test_map, a=2), [1, 1, 3])`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it makes more sense to use the [starmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) function.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_map(a,b):
    return a+b
p = Pool(4)
p.starmap(test_map, [(2,x) for x in [1, 1, 3]])
```