# Multiprocessing on parselmouth objects

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures, praat

I am trying to apply multiprocessing on parselmouth PRAAT functions to extract multiple functions.

```
 import concurrent.futures
 import time

 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(self.f1, ),executor.submit(self.f2, )]
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            data = future.result()
```

But I get this error which is the issue of unpicklable objects while multiprocessing:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

 TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-15-2dea24cd4bf1> in <module>
  2 strr = time.time()
  3 FeatureCalculateobj = FeatureCalculate(os.path.join(root,'P1_A2.wav'),async_flag=True)
  4 print(time.time()-strr)
  5 

  <ipython-input-13-f5b7e5b9fab3> in __init__(self, path, async_flag)
 26 
 27         if async_flag:
                self.main()
 29         else:
 30             self.str_pauses = self.extract_pauses_unasync()

  <ipython-input-13-f5b7e5b9fab3> in main(self)
176             futures = [executor.submit(self.jitter_shimmer, )]
177             for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                data = future.result()
179             print(data)
180 

 ~/miniconda3/envs/via_3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
        raise CancelledError()
427           elif self._state == FINISHED:
                 return self.__get_result()
429 
430             self._condition.wait(timeout)

  ~/miniconda3/envs/via_3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py in _feed(buffer, notempty, send_bytes, writelock, close, ignore_epipe, onerror, queue_sem)
234 
235                         # serialize the data before acquiring the lock
                 obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
237              if wacquire is None:
238                   send_bytes(obj)



~/miniconda3/envs/via_3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py 
 in dumps(cls, obj, protocol)
 49     def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
 50         buf = io.BytesIO()
            cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
 52         return buf.getbuffer()
 53 

         TypeError: can't pickle parselmouth.Sound objects
  cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj) TypeError: can't pickle parselmouth.Sound objects
```

Although I am not passing parselmouth.Sound objects as arguments to the class methods , I still get this error

Comment: what is **`cls`**?  Please provide the context that this is called in.

Comment: I have edited my question @ReinstateMonica

Comment: may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function

Comment: Can you provide the traceback too please?  This looks like a bug with the packages you are using.

Comment: Hey I have added the traceback @ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, apparently Parselmouth object don't support the pickle protocol yet (see the error message `TypeError: can't pickle parselmouth.Sound objects`). I had never thought of it in the context of multiprocessing, but it might be worth implementing for these kinds of use cases, indeed!

I'll see if I can get it in the next release. Something tells me it shouldn't be ridiculously hard :-)

Meanwhile, what you could probably do is write the file to a temporary directory, and read it again in each of the separate processes of `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiprocessing in Parselmouth by using Python's multiprocessing module and making sure the sounds are created in each process, also if on windows create the process in an `if __name__ == __main__` statement. asyncio is not for CPU-bound processes, like Parselmouth is, so multiprocessing is more appropriate. Here is a working example:

```
import parselmouth
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from glob import glob

# First make a function to multiprocess
def get_mean_pitch(filename):
    try:
        pitch = parselmouth.Sound(filename).to_pitch()
        mean_pitch = parselmouth.praat.call(pitch, "Get mean", 0, 0, "Hertz")
    except:
        mean_pitch = 0
    return mean_pitch

# Then make a list of wav files to iterate over
sound_filenames = sorted(glob("*.wav")

# Get the number of CPUs on the machine
cpus = cpu_count()

# Create a pool of CPUs
pool = Pool(cpus)

# Map the function over the list of files
results = pool.map(get_pitch, sound_filenames)
```