# What happens when a function's __qualname__ is changed in python?

Tags: python, pickle

In order to be able to pickle a nested function (for multiprocessing), I decorated the nested function with the decorator:

```
def globalize_one(func):
    def wrapper_one(*args,**kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    setattr(modules['__main__'],'sdfsdf',wrapper_one)
    return wrapper_one
```

However, this decorator does not work, when I ran this

```
def test_one():
    @globalize_one
    def inside_one():
        return 1

    try:
        pickle.dumps(inside_one)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

test_one()
```

I received the exception `Can't pickle local object 'globalize_one.<locals>.wrapper_one'`

To make the decorator work, all I need is to change the `__qualname__` of `wrapper_one` to `sdfsdf` in `globalize_one` right before the line `setattr(modules['__main__'],'sdfsdf',wrapper_one)`.

```
def globalize_two(func):
    def wrapper_two(*args,**kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs)

    # the single extra line as compared to globalize_one
    wrapper_two.__qualname__ = 'sdfsdf'

    setattr(modules['__main__'],'sdfsdf',wrapper_two)
    return wrapper_two

def test_two():
    @globalize_two
    def inside_two():
        return 1

    try:
        pickle.dumps(inside_two)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

As you can see by running the code, the nested function `inside_two` can be pickled now.

My confusion is, why by changing the `__qualname__`, the decorator will work properly? I thought changing the name of a function have no real effect.

Comment: I'm curious what you read that made you think of changing the `__qualname__`?

Comment: why do you need to pickle a function? I always thought of pickle as a way to store instance data on disc so you can retrieve this instance from disc again - but you would need the classes definition in the code that pickles and unpickles the file? (just curious, followed and uv to see how this Q develops)

Comment: @PatrickArtner because that's how multiprocessing works. The function is pickled before being passed to the separate processes. It's not just a file format but a way to serialize objects and pass them between processes

Comment: @PatrickArtner maybe the most relevant part of the docs is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) but I'm not aware of a decent treatise on the overall use of pickle in the process

Comment: Not sure if you saw that alreadybut [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function) they use a fork of multiprocess that can pickle "better" using _dill_ (which almost makes sense as dill is a herb used to pickle cucumbers to make them more tasty:D ) - thread is 8y old so not sure its still valid and applicable to your situation

Comment: @PatrickArtner to my knowledge, `dill` is still the go-to for this. I don't think we're any closer to answering this question, though. It seems very strange that `__qualname__` does anything with pickle to fix this issue. It's going on my watch list :)

Comment: @roganjosh Actually, I didn't think of changing the `__qualname__` and only have `setattr(modules['__main__'],'sdfsdf',wrapper)` in the first place. Then, I realized by only doing this, `python` will never know when to call `sdfsdf`, so I changed the `__qualname__` of `wrapper` to 'sdfsdf'. By running more tests, I think the solution lies within the way how `pickle` pickles a function, I have asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64095346/8366805) about this, hope you can check it out :)