# pickle: how does it pickle a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

In a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086529/8366805) I posted yesterday, I accidentally found changing the `__qualname__` of a function has an unexpected effect on `pickle`. By running more tests, I found that when pickling a function, `pickle` does not work in the way I thought, and changing the `__qualname__` of the function has a real effect on how `pickle` behaves.

The snippets below are tests I ran,

```
import pickle
from sys import modules

# a simple function to pickle 
def hahaha(): return 1

print('hahaha',hahaha,'\n')

# change the __qualname__ of function hahaha
hahaha.__qualname__ = 'sdfsdf'
print('set hahaha __qualname__ to sdfsdf',hahaha,'\n')

# make a copy of hahaha
setattr(modules['__main__'],'abcabc',hahaha)
print('create abcabc which is just hahaha',abcabc,'\n')

try:
    pickle.dumps(hahaha)
except Exception as e:
    print('pickle hahaha')
    print(e,'\n')

try:
    pickle.dumps(abcabc)
except Exception as e:
    print('pickle abcabc, a copy of hahaha')
    print(e,'\n')

try:
    pickle.dumps(sdfsdf)
except Exception as e:
    print('pickle sdfsdf')
    print(e)
```

As you can see by running the snippets, both `hahaha` and `abcabc` cannot be pickled because of the exception:

`Can't pickle <function sdfsdf at 0x7fda36dc5f28>: attribute lookup sdfsdf on __main__ failed`.

I'm really confused by this exception,

1. What does `pickle` look for when it pickles a function? Although the `__qualname__` of `hahaha` was changed to 'sdfsdf', the function `hahaha` as well as its copy `abcabc` is still callable in the session (as they are in `dir(sys.modules['__main__'])`), then why `pickle` cannot pickle them?
2. What is the real effect of changing the `__qualname__` of a function? I understand by changing the `__qualname__` of `hahaha` to 'sdfsdf' won't make `sdfsdf` callable, as it won't show up in `dir(sys.modules['__main__'])`. However, as you can see by running the snippets, after changing the `__qualname__` of `hahaha` to 'sdfsdf', the object `hahaha` as well as its copy `abcabc` has changed to something like `<function sdfsdf at 'some_address'>`. What is the difference between the objects in `sys.modules['__main__']` and `<function sdfsdf at 'some_address'>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pickling of function objects is defined in the [`save_global` method in pickle.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pickle.py#L1053):

First, the name of the function is retrieved via `__qualname__`:

```
name = getattr(obj, '__qualname__', None)
```

Afterwards, after retrieving the module, it is reimported:

```
__import__(module_name, level=0)
module = sys.modules[module_name]
```

This freshly imported `module` is then used to look up the function as an attribute:

```
obj2, parent = _getattribute(module, name)
```

`obj2` would now be a new copy of the function, but since `sdfsdf` doesn't exist in this module, pickling fails here.

---

You can make this work, but you have to be consistent:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pickle
>>> def hahaha(): return 1
>>> hahaha.__qualname__ = "sdfsdf"
>>> setattr(sys.modules["__main__"], "sdfsdf", hahaha)
>>> pickle.dumps(hahaha)
b'\x80\x04\x95\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x06sdfsdf\x94\x93\x94.'
```