# Can't pickle with local class imported

Tags: pytorch, pickle, python-multiprocessing, distributed

As long as I import class from my own library, my pickle failed, why?
For example:

```
def fun():
   print(1)
if __name__=="__main__":
   import pickle
   pickle.dump(fun, open('save', 'wb'))
```

The script above works fine, but if I add `from xxx.yyy import zzz` (my class from my local library):

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fun at 0x7f5e40665e18>: attribute lookup fun on __main__ failed` occurs.

Why? Is there any workaround? By the way, the problem originally occurs when I was trying to use `torch.multiprocessing` for distributed training, then I reduce the problem to above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function)

Comment: @GaiusJulius no, i saw that one before, and i checked pickle doc that describes what cant be pickled. i am confused why i could import class from other libs and pickle stuff, but once i import a class from my library, i cant pickle, and the thing i was trying to pickle has nothing to do with the class i imported

Answer (score 0):

The script above works fine, but if I add `from xxx.yyy import zzz` (my class from my local library):

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fun at 0x7f5e40665e18>: attribute lookup fun on **main** failed occurs.

I just meet the same error, after I comment the `import ipdb`, the error is gone.