# How to start multiprocessing network manager with multiple queues in separate process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to Python. Is it possible to run a multi-queue manager over the network in separate process?

I'm trying to write, this is what happened at the moment:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time

address = "127.0.0.1"
password = "secret"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        work_tasks_queue = manager.Queue()
        done_task_queue = manager.Queue()

        class QueueManager(BaseManager):
            pass


        QueueManager.register('work_tasks_queue', callable=lambda: work_tasks_queue)
        QueueManager.register('done_task_queue', callable=lambda: done_task_queue)

        net_manager = QueueManager(address=(address, 50000), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))

        net_manager.start()

        print("------------------------------------------------------")
```

At the moment, I managed to start the network manager with several queues.

I want to start server in separate process. I want to be able to process both queues within one script (add new jobs for processing or mark completed tasks).

It looks like I can do that. Here's an example. I did the same.

https://github.com/shariq/burgundy/blob/master/remotequeue.py

But in my case, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WORKSPACE\check_manager_in_event\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    net_manager.start()
  File "C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 553, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000020B330551F0>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using Python 3.9 on Windows 10 Professional in Pycharm Community IDE.

Can someone help in solving this problem?

Comment: This may work but is not reliable. Consider celery or other distributed task queue.

Comment: Changed the code a bit. The process starts. But the main process hangs along with it.

Comment: Can you explain your point of view in more detail with an example (if possible)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few subtleties. First, when you register with a manager a function that returns an object, the manager by default will attempt to build a proxy for that object. But the object you are returning is a managed queue that *is already* a proxied object. You should therefore just be returning an *ordinary* queue instance as in the [second example in **Using a Remote Manager**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers).

The following code can be started with argument *server* to start up the remote manager, *workers* to start up a process pool of 3 processes where each process reads from the `work_tasks_queue` expecting an integer and writes a tuple to the `task_done_queue` queue consisting of the integer and the square of the integer as the result or with no argument to start the client that writes 10 integers to the `work_tasks_queue` queue and then reads the 10 results from the `task_done_queue` queue, which may be in arbitrary order.

There seems to be a bug with authentication and it becomes necessary for each process in the process pool to initialize its own process as follows or the manager will reject requests:

```py
current_process().authkey = password.encode('utf-8')
```

Needless to say, the server, workers and client would typically (or at least, possibly) be run on 3 different machines (with an adjustment to the `address` specification).

**Common QueueManager.py Module**

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 50000
password = "secret"

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def connect_to_manager():
    QueueManager.register('work_tasks_queue')
    QueueManager.register('done_task_queue')
    manager = QueueManager(address=(address, port), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))
    manager.connect()
    return manager.work_tasks_queue(), manager.done_task_queue()
```

**server.py**

```py
from QueueManager import *
from queue import Queue

work_tasks_queue = Queue()
done_task_queue = Queue()

def get_work_tasks_queue():
    return work_tasks_queue

def get_done_task_queue():
    return done_task_queue

def server():
    # Don't seem to be able to use a lambda or nested function when using net_manager.start():
    QueueManager.register('work_tasks_queue', callable=get_work_tasks_queue)
    QueueManager.register('done_task_queue', callable=get_done_task_queue)

    net_manager = QueueManager(address=(address, port), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))

    net_manager.start()
    input('Server starting. Hit Enter to terminate....')
    net_manager.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

**workers.py**

```py
from QueueManager import *
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, cpu_count
from threading import Thread

def worker(in_q, out_q):
    current_process().authkey = password.encode('utf-8')
    while True:
        x = in_q.get()
        if x is None: # signal to terminate
            in_q.task_done()
            break
        out_q.put((x, x ** 2))
        in_q.task_done()

def create_workers(in_q, out_q, n_workers):
    processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(in_q, out_q)) for _ in range(n_workers)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

def start_workers():
    N_WORKERS = cpu_count()
    in_q, out_q = connect_to_manager()
    t = Thread(target=create_workers, args=(in_q, out_q, N_WORKERS))
    t.start()
    input('Starting workers. Hit enter to terminate...')
    for _ in range(N_WORKERS):
        in_q.put(None) # tell worker to quit
    #in_q.join() # not strictly necessary; assumes client's work has been completed too
    t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_workers()
```

**client.py**

```py
from QueueManager import *

def client():
    in_q, out_q = connect_to_manager()
    for x in range(1, 10):
        in_q.put(x)
    # get results as they become available:
    for x in range(1, 10):
        x, result = out_q.get()
        print(x, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

Prints:

```
1 1
4 16
3 9
2 4
5 25
6 36
8 64
7 49
9 81
```

**Update**

Here is code to run everything all together.

```py
from QueueManager import *
from workers import create_workers
from client import client
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, Event

# So that queues are not unnecessarily created by worker processes under Windows:
work_tasks_queue = None
done_task_queue = None

def get_work_tasks_queue():
    global work_tasks_queue
    # singleton:
    if work_tasks_queue is None:
        work_tasks_queue = Queue()
    return work_tasks_queue

def get_done_task_queue():
    global done_task_queue
    # singleton:
    if done_task_queue is None:
        done_task_queue = Queue()
    return done_task_queue

def server(started_event, shutdown_event):
    # Don't seem to be able to use a lambda or nested function when using net_manager.start():
    QueueManager.register('work_tasks_queue', callable=get_work_tasks_queue)
    QueueManager.register('done_task_queue', callable=get_done_task_queue)

    net_manager = QueueManager(address=(address, port), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))

    net_manager.start()
    started_event.set() # tell main thread that we have started
    shutdown_event.wait() # wait to be told to shutdown
    net_manager.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    started_event = Event()
    shutdown_event = Event()
    server_thread = Thread(target=server, args=(started_event, shutdown_event,))
    server_thread.start()
    # wait for manager to start:
    started_event.wait()
    in_q, out_q = connect_to_manager()
    N_WORKERS = 3
    workers_thread = Thread(target=create_workers, args=(in_q, out_q, N_WORKERS,))
    workers_thread.start()
    client()
    # tell workers we are through:
    for _ in range(N_WORKERS):
        in_q.put(None)
    #in_q.join() # not strictly necessary; assumes client's work has been completed too
    workers_thread.join()
    # tell manager we are through:
    shutdown_event.set()
    server_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Appreciate your help. I am new to python. Tomorrow I will study your proposed solution. In general, my goal is to move the server process that manages the queues into a separate script that will manage the queue, and make the worker processes separate scripts. This is necessary for solving a complex problem of processing large data (as a distributed ETL process, in which data extraction will be taken into a separate process).

Comment: Can you please tell me, do I understand correctly that it will not work to use the JoinableQueue() remotely? I need to somehow inform the queue manager process that the task has completed successfully.

Comment: The "ordinary" `queue.Queue` instance, which is now being proxied by the `QueueManager` class already supports `task_done` and `join` methods. Therefore, you should have no need to use a `JoinableQueue`. I have added an update that runs manager (server), workers, and client all in one script and I have included calls to `task_done` and `join`, although the logic of this code does not require "joining" the `work_tasks_queue`.

Comment: But see the comment made by @Aaron for a more robust solution, if you need it, and it sounds like you may.

Comment: I have updated both code examples to use Process instances rather than a process pool since that makes more sense since they are getting their input from a queue. The first example also terminates more gracefully and uses a special `None` record in the `work_tasks_queue` to signify to a worker process that it is to terminate.

Comment: Many human thanks! You have helped a lot. My level of knowledge of the Python language is enough to understand your solution, but you used really simple and ingenious tricks. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Not being able to leave well enough, I have 1. broken out the code into separate server, workers and client modules and 2. changed the server to use a different method of running (`net_manager.start()`), which doesn't block and thus allows me to positively tell the starter in the second example that the manager is now running rather than having to delay for 1 second.

Comment: This is a great idea. Thank you so much. When I finish developing and uploading it to github, I will definitely indicate in the repository about your contribution and invaluable help. Great job!

Comment: I think this example will help a lot of young developers, because the test library is good, but it lacks examples and some depth of explanation in the documentation, which creates a barrier in understanding and opening prospects.