# pyqt5 freezing issue

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qtimer

example.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'example.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.player_list_table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.player_list_table.setObjectName("player_list_table")
        self.player_list_table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.player_list_table.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.player_list_table, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timeline = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.timeline.setMaximum(100)
        self.timeline.setPageStep(1)
        self.timeline.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.timeline.setObjectName("timeline")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.timeline, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.refresh_table = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.refresh_table.setObjectName("refresh_table")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.refresh_table, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.refresh_table.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh table"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

example_code.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from example import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap,QBrush
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Example_Code:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)     
        self.app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats")
        self.app.setStyle("Fusion")
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.main_ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self.mainWindow)
        self.mainWindow.showMaximized()
        
        #A QTimer which set value to QSlider
        self.slider_position = 0
        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move_slider)
        self.timer.start(125)
        
        #display table contents
        self.display_table()
        
        #on button press refresh table
        self.main_ui.refresh_table.clicked.connect(self.display_table)
        
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def move_slider(self):
        self.slider_position +=1
        self.main_ui.timeline.setValue(self.slider_position)
        if(self.slider_position>100):
            self.slider_position = 0
            
    def display_table(self):
        palette = self.main_ui.player_list_table.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Highlight,QBrush(Qt.white))
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.HighlightedText,QBrush(Qt.black))
        
        row = 0
        
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setWordWrap(True)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        
        self.player_list_data_length = 100
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setRowCount(0)
        for player_list_row in range(0,100):
            self.main_ui.player_list_table.insertRow(player_list_row)
            for j in range(0,5):
                self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
                self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 355, 231))
                self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
                self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
                self.image_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image_title.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image_title.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.image_title.setWordWrap(True)
                self.image_title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image_title, 1, 0, 1, 3)
                self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setText("")
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.setObjectName("image")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
                spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                
                pixmap = QPixmap("test.png").scaledToHeight(150)
                self.image.setPixmap(pixmap)
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.resize(150, 150)
                
                self.image_title.setText("\n\n test.png")
                self.frame.update()
                self.main_ui.player_list_table.setCellWidget(player_list_row,j,self.frame)
                
        header = self.main_ui.player_list_table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.Alignment(QtCore.Qt.TextWordWrap))
        for i in range(0,5):
            header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)      
        
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item {border: 0px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }")
    
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setPalette(palette)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        
        print("Table updated")
            
            
program = Example_Code()
```

1. Put a png image with filename test.png to project directory.
2. Change line: `self.app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats")` to be correct (this is for openning any image format)
3. Run the app with `python example_code.py
4. Push the refresh table button.
5. When you push this button the QSlider Animation is freezing for some seconds.

**Edit:**

I tried to use QThread but doesn't work (Opens 100*5=500 new windows because

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different t
hread.
```

)

file: example_code.py (updated but didn't work)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from example import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap,QBrush
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys
import time

# Step 1: Create a worker class
class Worker(QObject):
    set_row_count = pyqtSignal(int)
    insert_row = pyqtSignal(int)
    cell_ready = pyqtSignal(int,int,QtWidgets.QFrame)
    table_ready = pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        row = 0
        self.set_row_count.emit(0)
        for player_list_row in range(0,100):
            self.insert_row.emit(player_list_row)
            for j in range(0,5):
                self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
                self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 355, 231))
                self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
                self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
                self.image_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image_title.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image_title.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.image_title.setWordWrap(True)
                self.image_title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image_title, 1, 0, 1, 3)
                self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setText("")
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.setObjectName("image")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
                spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                
                pixmap = QPixmap("test.png").scaledToHeight(150)
                self.image.setPixmap(pixmap)
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.resize(150, 150)
                
                self.image_title.setText("\n\n test.png")
                self.frame.update()
                self.cell_ready.emit(player_list_row,j,self.frame)
                time.sleep(1)
                #if you remove the up line there is segmentation fault error
                
        self.table_ready.emit()
        
        

class Example_Code:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)     
        self.app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats")
        self.app.setStyle("Fusion")
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.main_ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self.mainWindow)
        self.mainWindow.showMaximized()
        
        #A QTimer which set value to QSlider
        self.slider_position = 0
        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move_slider)
        self.timer.start(125)
        
        #display table contents
        self.display_table()
        
        #on button press refresh table
        self.main_ui.refresh_table.clicked.connect(self.refresh_table_method)
        
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def refresh_table_method(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.table_ready.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.table_ready.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
        
        self.worker.set_row_count.connect(self.set_row_count_method)
        self.worker.insert_row.connect(self.insert_new_row)
        self.worker.cell_ready.connect(self.display_cell)
        self.worker.table_ready.connect(self.refresh_finished)
        
    def set_row_count_method(self,rows):
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setRowCount(rows)
        
    def insert_new_row(self,row):
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.insertRow(row)
        
    def display_cell(self,row,column,the_widget):
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setCellWidget(row,column,the_widget)
        
    def refresh_finished(self,row):
        print("Table refreshed")
        
        
    def move_slider(self):
        self.slider_position +=1
        self.main_ui.timeline.setValue(self.slider_position)
        if(self.slider_position>100):
            self.slider_position = 0
            
    def display_table(self):
        palette = self.main_ui.player_list_table.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Highlight,QBrush(Qt.white))
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.HighlightedText,QBrush(Qt.black))
                
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setWordWrap(True)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        
        self.player_list_data_length = 100
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setRowCount(0)
        for player_list_row in range(0,100):
            self.main_ui.player_list_table.insertRow(player_list_row)
            for j in range(0,5):
                self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
                self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 355, 231))
                self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
                self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
                self.image_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image_title.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image_title.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.image_title.setWordWrap(True)
                self.image_title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\nborder:none;\n}")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image_title, 1, 0, 1, 3)
                self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.image.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.image.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.image.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
                self.image.setText("")
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.setObjectName("image")
                self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.image, 0, 1, 1, 1)
                spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
                spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
                
                pixmap = QPixmap("test.png").scaledToHeight(150)
                self.image.setPixmap(pixmap)
                self.image.setScaledContents(True)
                self.image.resize(150, 150)
                
                self.image_title.setText("\n\n test.png")
                self.frame.update()
                self.main_ui.player_list_table.setCellWidget(player_list_row,j,self.frame)
                
        header = self.main_ui.player_list_table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.Alignment(QtCore.Qt.TextWordWrap))
        for i in range(0,5):
            header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)      
        
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item {border: 0px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }")
    
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setPalette(palette)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.main_ui.player_list_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
            
            
program = Example_Code()
```

Comment: Please provide **minimal** (essential) code and description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I am trying to update a QTableWidget with 22 columns and unknown rows, with no application freezing.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I think the upper code is as minimal as it can be to produce the problem.

Comment: I really think to "downgrade-use" tkinter. What do you think?

Comment: Creating hundreds of widgets takes time. If you are just using them to display text labels and a pixmaps in a QTableWidget you could consider sub-classing QStyledItemDelegate and override paint and sizeHint to draw the pixmap and text for each item.