# python attribute error : can't pickle local object. Using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I am writing a program that aims at wrapping a C code starting a phasemeter acquisition.

This code is supposed to be run on several process at the same time so I use `multiprocessing`.

I read nearly all answered questions on SO on this subject but I think i'm missing something. I would be glad if someone could give me a hand on this one.

I have the following error :

> wdir='/home/castaing/Documents/LISA/lisa_zifo_monitoring/Python
> Drivers/Phasemeter/Py_Code') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/castaing/Documents/LISA/lisa_zifo_monitoring/Python
> Drivers/Phasemeter/Py_Code/DriverPhasemeter.py", line 297, in 
> Process.map(start,Phasemeter.phase_list)
>
> File
> "/home/castaing/anaconda3/envs/LISA/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> line 268, in map
> return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>
> File
> "/home/castaing/anaconda3/envs/LISA/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> line 657, in get
> raise self._value
>
> File
> "/home/castaing/anaconda3/envs/LISA/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> line 431, in _handle_tasks
> put(task)
>
> File
> "/home/castaing/anaconda3/envs/LISA/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py",
> line 206, in send
> self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
>
> File
> "/home/castaing/anaconda3/envs/LISA/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py",
> line 51, in dumps
> cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
>
> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object
> 'CDLL.**init**.._FuncPtr'

I tried to define a global function to call the phasemeter object's method as you can see below. At the beginning I had a multistart method in the phasemeter object which code was :

```
def multistart(self) : 
   with multiprocessing.Pool(len(Phasemeter.phase_list)) as Process :
        Process.map(lambda x :x.start,Phasemeter.phase_list)
```

Here is the code (I only put the parts that seemed relevant to me) :

```
#%% Initialization

#%% Function definition

#Fix pickle problem ?
def start(Phasemeter_object):
    Phasemeter_object.start()
        
#%% Class definiton
class Phasemeter :
    # List of all phasemeters objects, accessed by calling Phasemeter.phase_list
    phase_list=[]
    
    #%% Initialization
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) :
        #%% Robustness. Check type of passed arguments 

        #%% Path setting, parsing config file 
        
        #%% Option handling

        #%% Debug, used only if verbose argument is passed in start method 
        
        #%% Defining path to shared object file
        self.path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                               self.path_to_so_file))
        
        # LIBC is now an object and its method are C Code's functions
        self.LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(self.path)

        # Settings C library's signature datatype with ctypes data structre tool
        # INFO: To see all datas types that can be transmited to C Code
        # read ctypes documentation
        # First argument is int : argc
        # Second argument is string array : argv
        # Third is a string : path_to_log_file
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.argtypes= [ctypes.c_int,
                                            ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),
                                            ctypes.c_char_p,]
        # Return type is int : Return code
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.restypes = [ctypes.c_int,]
        
        # Add object to phase_list, list used in multistart method 
        Phasemeter.phase_list.append(self)

    #%% Start
    def start(self):
        #%% Marshalling data for C library
        # Create a string array with option list length size
        self.c_char_pointer_array = ctypes.c_char_p * len(self.options)
        # Encode option list
        self.encoded_options = [str.encode(str(i)) for i in self.options ]
        # Fill the string array with encoded strings
        # REMINDER: C code only understand encoded strings
        self.encoded_options = self.c_char_pointer_array (*self.encoded_options)


        #%% Calling C library wihth encoded options
        # If the logfile option is activated then the encoded 
        # string is transmited
        if self.encoded_path_to_log_file :
            self.status = self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main(
                len(self.encoded_options),
                self.encoded_options,
                self.encoded_path_to_log_file)
        # Otherwise None pointer is transmited
        else :
            self.status = self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main(len(self.encoded_options),
                                                      self.encoded_options,None)
#%% Multistart
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # This function is used to start acquisition on multiple phasemeters 
    my_phase = Phasemeter(name="PH1")
    my_phase = Phasemeter(name="PH2")
    with multiprocessing.Pool(len(Phasemeter.phase_list)) as Process :
        Process.map(start,Phasemeter.phase_list)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805244/15826727

Comment: That's what I thought but I tried the proposed solution and it doesn't work

Comment: However i may have missed something, any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved half of your problem by getting rid of your lambda function. But now you are still in a "pickle." In your `Phasemeter.__init__` method you have:

```py
        self.LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(self.path)
```

That code executes in the main process while method `Phasemeter.start` is being executed in a different process. Therefore, there is attempt to serialize/deserialize `self.LIBC` from one address space to another using `pickle`, and this fails. I would suggest postponing setting this attribute until the `start` method so that it does not have to be pickled:

```py
import multiprocessing

#%% Initialization

#%% Function definition

#Fix pickle problem ?
def start(Phasemeter_object):
    Phasemeter_object.start()
        
#%% Class definiton
class Phasemeter :
    # List of all phasemeters objects, accessed by calling Phasemeter.phase_list
    phase_list=[]
    
    #%% Initialization
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) :
        #%% Robustness. Check type of passed arguments 

        #%% Path setting, parsing config file 
        
        #%% Option handling

        #%% Debug, used only if verbose argument is passed in start method 
        
        #%% Defining path to shared object file
        self.path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                               self.path_to_so_file))
                
        # Add object to phase_list, list used in multistart method 
        Phasemeter.phase_list.append(self)

    #%% Start
    def start(self):
        # LIBC is now an object and its method are C Code's functions
        self.LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(self.path)

        # Settings C library's signature datatype with ctypes data structre tool
        # INFO: To see all datas types that can be transmited to C Code
        # read ctypes documentation
        # First argument is int : argc
        # Second argument is string array : argv
        # Third is a string : path_to_log_file
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.argtypes= [ctypes.c_int,
                                            ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),
                                            ctypes.c_char_p,]
        # Return type is int : Return code
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.restypes = [ctypes.c_int,]

        #%% Marshalling data for C library
        # Create a string array with option list length size
        self.c_char_pointer_array = ctypes.c_char_p * len(self.options)
        # Encode option list
        self.encoded_options = [str.encode(str(i)) for i in self.options ]
        # Fill the string array with encoded strings
        # REMINDER: C code only understand encoded strings
        self.encoded_options = self.c_char_pointer_array (*self.encoded_options)


        #%% Calling C library wihth encoded options
        # If the logfile option is activated then the encoded 
        # string is transmited
        if self.encoded_path_to_log_file :
            self.status = self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main(
                len(self.encoded_options),
                self.encoded_options,
                self.encoded_path_to_log_file)
        # Otherwise None pointer is transmited
        else :
            self.status = self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main(len(self.encoded_options),
                                                      self.encoded_options,None)
#%% Multistart
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # This function is used to start acquisition on multiple phasemeters 
    my_phase = Phasemeter(name="PH1")
    my_phase = Phasemeter(name="PH2")
    with multiprocessing.Pool(len(Phasemeter.phase_list)) as Process :
        Process.map(start,Phasemeter.phase_list)
```

As a bonus you are parallelizing more code.

Comment: It worked like a charm ! Thank you a lot ! May you link any resource to help me understand why it's like that ?

Comment: Not really. But it should be clear that all arguments that are passed to your worker functions (here you are using `map` to specify the arguments) need to be serialized/deserialized from one address space to another. Your  `Phasemeter.__init__` method is being run by the main process so the objects you were passing to `map` had as attributes `self.LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(self.path)`, which being part of the object had to be pickled to the new address space but couldn't be. The solution is to set that attribute in `Phasemeter.start`, which is running in the pool process.

Comment: Oh okay that's a good answer, thank you a lot. I wish I could tip you some BATs. Have a nice day

Comment: That "you are in a pickle" comment made my day (also a great answer)