# Parallel map with nested functions that depend on modules

Tags: python, module, parallel-processing, functional-programming, nested

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to parallelize

```
import numpy as np

def generate_function(a):
    def func(x):
        '''a complex function that uses several modules'''
        return x + np.sqrt(a)
    return func

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = generate_function(0.5)
    x = np.arange(0, 100)
    y = np.array(list(map(f, x))) # want to parallelize this step
```

with `multiprocessing`, the nested `func` causes problems, since `pickle` can't access nested functions

```
import multiprocessing as mp
...
pool = mp.Pool(2)
y = np.array(pool.map(f, x))

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'generate_function.<locals>.func'
```

even with `pathos`, the modules are not imported

```
import pathos
...
pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool(2)
y = np.array(pool.map(f, x))

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Note that none of the other solutions on [Python multiprocessing PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function/) work either

What's the best way to parallelize this?

---

So it *is possible* to get `pathos` to work by reimporting inside of `generate_function`

```
def generate_function(a):
    import numpy as np
    def func(x):
        '''a complex function that uses several modules'''
        return x + np.sqrt(a)
    return func
```

but I may have several imports with multiple `generate_function`s and multiple layers of nesting, and it will quickly get quite cumbersome keeping track of all that, so I would like to avoid this mess

```
def generate_function1(a):
    import module1, module2, module3
    from module4 import a, b
    from module5 import c as d
    from module6 import e as f
    def func(x):
        ...
    return func

def generate_function2(a):
    import module1, module2, module3
    from module4 import a, b
    from module5 import c as d
    from module6 import e as f
    def func(x):
        ...
    return func

def generate_generator_function(a):
    import module1, module2, module3
    from module4 import a, b
    from module5 import c as d
    from module6 import e as f
    def generate_function(a):
        import module1, module2, module3
        from module4 import a, b
        from module5 import c as d
        from module6 import e as f
        def func(x):
            ...
        return func
    return generate_function
```

Comment: Have you considered using classes?

Comment: @kpie I'm not sure how that would work when the `func`s must be generated dynamically

Comment: Do you have to use `np.arange` or can you use a simple `range`?

Comment: Try to explicitly import np inside the def-s executed inside the remote pathos-processes. Pathos, as Mike McKearns noted here, can use pass-by-SER/DES but where-feasible can pass-by-SOURCE ( instead of pickle-dill SER/DES ) and there we are, your code can work fine in main, not so in remote, pathos-spawned, independent process, whereas the def-ed source-code can import ALAP the numpy module therein J.I.T. ( give it a try ... )

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve your pickle problems but here's my thinking with classes to manage your imports.

```
>>> class funcFactory:
...     import numpy as np
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...     def makef(self,a):
...             def func(x):
...                     return a+funcFactory.np.sqrt(x)
...             return func
...
>>> ff = funcFactory()
>>> f = ff.makef(1)
>>> f(4)
3.0
```

Incorporating @Schotty's suggestion to use concurrent.futures you end up with code that looks like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

class funcFactory:
    import numpy as np
    def makef(self,a):
        def func(x):
            return a+funcFactory.np.sqrt(x)
        func.__reduce__ = lambda:""
        return func

f = funcFactory().makef(0.5)
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
    y = ex.map(f, np.arange(0, 100))
print(list(y))
```

Comment: Copy of idea? What if the idea was brutally wrong? Python Threads, since ever were GIL-lock ( a MUTEX blocking trick ), so principally re-[SERIAL]-ising the flow of processing ... so never making even a trivial "just"-[CONCURRENT] flow of processing ever happen here ( an only fair use cases were in network & similar End-2-End transactions' latency-masking, just using the O/S resources to do it ), the less a True-[PARALLEL] ... ouch! ) If Python has ( without telling Guido von ROSSUM ) escaped from GIL-lock, that should have made a giant wave of celebrations in media - did I miss that?

Comment: you missed nothing. But this is still the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `concurrent.futures`:

```py
import concurrent.futures

f = generate_function(0.5)
x = np.arange(0, 100)
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
    y = ex.map(f, x)
```

Comment: That's a good look.

Comment: Doesn't `ThreadPoolExecutor` use threads? I do actually need multiprocess because of the GIL, and replacing it with `ProcessPoolExecutor` still creates the same issues. Besides, for some reason threads don't play well with my actual program because while using threads work in the test example, it crashes my actual program with 0xC0000005

Comment: Did I miss some Python news here? Python Threads, since ever were GIL-lock ( MUTEX blocking, so principally re-[SERIAL]-ising the flow of processing ... so never making even a trivial "just"-[CONCURRENT] flow of processing ever happen here, the less a True-[PARALLEL] ... ouch! ) If Python has ( without telling Guido von ROSSUM ) escaped from GIL-lock, that should have made a giant wave of celebrations in media - did I miss some kind of that?