# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'SharedMemoryDisplay.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am working with this object SharedMemoryDisplay in the above script and I want to return/retrieve self.camera_container, where `self.camera_container = {camera_id: (camera_id, frame, frame_properties)}`
I tried to create a method to return the this but it gives two errors

```
   prop, camera_container = monitor_memory.get_frame()
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
   AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'SharedMemoryDisplay.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

I am only able to able to get self.camera_container[key] if I just do which is fine but I want to get self.camera_container also.

```
 return self.camera_container[key]
```

In the below script is where, I am using this object to display in a cv2 named window, my ultimate motive is to retrieve frames of all the cameras seperately what it currently does is joins all the camera frames and returns that via self.display_frame which is added to `webdisplay_memory` in the below script (for displaying in the html) that's why I created a method to retrieve dictionary `camera_container`.
webdisplay_memory.add_frame(0, self.display_frame, None)
rather than messing with this variable I was thinking of creating a method that returns `self.camera_container` than using this to get frames of each camera seperately.

how can I overcome this, kindly help if you have better and efficient solutions!

Comment: you attempted to inline some questionable javascript files from an off-site resource. please review your post and [edit] it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` under the hood. `pickle` can serialize only a certain [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) of objects. Specifically, it can not serialize `defaultdict` (a type for your `camera_container`). So, either use a normal `dict` and replace all the lookups to `self.camera_container.get(key, None)`, or look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function) and try to use `pathos.multiprocessing` with `dill`. The latter approach is not tested by me, though.

Comment: thanks a lot @AndreySobolev I did this ```self.camera_container = dict(self.camera_container)``` and it worked.