# Python, Input-list-append

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
RandomList = []

def endless():

    x = input("x: ")
    RandomList.append(x)
    print(RandomList)

endless()
```

I want to make a list where Input() gets appended to RandomList, and the numbers gets to stay there for ever even if I close the file. I don't really know whether it can be done or not. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Storing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913261/python-storing-data)

Comment: You should add some loop to make input and store process truly endless. In each loop you need to add code to save the list to a file. Search for "loops in python" and "saving to file in python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make objects persistent, one module you could use would be the pickle module.

One example would be:

```
import pickle

RandomList = []

with open('randomlist_persistence', 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(RandomList, outp)
```

This would save the RandomList list object to a file. To then access it again, you can use:

```
with open('randomlist_persistence', 'rb') as inp:
    RandomList = pickle.load(inp)
```

Bear in mind, opening the file in write-mode will overwrite the list, so if you want to *ammend* a list, ensure you open the file in read mode **first**, save the list to a variable *and then* open it again it write-mode and re-write it.

I.e.

```
with open('randomlist_persistence', 'rb') as inp:
    RandomList = pickle.load(inp)

...... do any modifications here ......

with open('randomlist_persistence', 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(RandomList, outp)
```

Hopefully this helps. More information on the pickle module can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle