# Python3.4 pickle dump function fails with TypeError

Tags: python

I have a simple script that is suppose to import a module that initializes a db dictionary. The script then should open a file and use pickle.dump to write the db dictionary to the file. However it fails with the following TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_db_pickle.py", line 6, in <module>
    pickle.dump(db, dbfile)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

from initdata import db
import pickle
dbfile = open('people_pickle', 'w')
pickle.dump(db, dbfile)
dbfile.close()
```

The type function show my variables dbfile and db as:

```
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906623/using-pickle-dump-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to open in binary mode i.e `wb`:

```
 open('people_pickle', 'wb')
```

Comment: the solution provided works.  Can you explain what the TraceBack is reporting: TypeError: must be str, not bytes. I don't understand what must be a str.

Comment: @dcrearer, when you open a file using just "w" then  the file object is expecting a str  i.e  `open("foo.bin","w").write("foo")` works fine but `open("foo.bin","w").write("foo".encode("utf-8"))` will give you `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` as we have encoded the str to bytes which is what pickle also does, that is why you need to open in binary mode,  `open("foo.bin","wb").write("foo".encode("utf-8"))` would work fine .