# Rock paper scissors menu error

Tags: python

Here is code I have so far whenever the menu appears and I press 1 for start a new game it says wrong choice try again.

```
import random
import pickle

class GameStatus():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.tie = 0

        self.playerWon = 0

        self.pcWon = 0

        self.name = name

    def get_round(self):

        return self.tie + self.playerWon + self.pcWon + 1

# Displays program information, starts main play loop

def main():

    print("Welcome to a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!")

    print("What would you like to choose?")

    print("")

    game_status = welcomemenu()

    while True:
        play(game_status)

        endGameSelect(game_status)

def welcomemenu():
    while True:
        print("[1]: Start New Game")

        print("[2]: Load Game")

        print("[3]: Quit")

        print("")

        menuselect = input("Enter your choice: ")

        if menuselect in [1, 2, 3]:

            break

        else:

            print("Wrong choice. select again.")

    if menuselect == 1:

        name = input("What is your name?: ")

        print("Hello %s.") % name

        print("Let's play!")

        game_status = GameStatus(name)

    elif menuselect == 2:

        while True:

            name = input("What is your name?: ")

            try:

                player_file = open('%s.rsp' % name, 'r')

            except IOError:

                print("Sorry there is no game found with name %s") % name

                continue

            break

        print("Welcome back %s.") % name

        print("Let's play!")

        game_status = pickle.load(player_file)

        displayScoreBoard(game_status)

        player_file.close()

    elif menuselect == 3:

        print("Bye!!!")

        exit()

        return

    return game_status

def play(game_status):

    playerChoice = int(playerMenu())

    pcChoice = pcGenerate()

    outcome = evaluateGame(playerChoice, pcChoice)

    updateScoreBoard(outcome, game_status)

def playerMenu():
    print("Select a choice: \n [1]: Rock \n [2]: Paper \n [3]: Scissors\n")

    menuSelect = input("What will it be? ")

    while not validateInput(menuSelect):

        invalidChoice(menuSelect)

        menuSelect = input("Enter a correct value: ")

    return menuSelect

def validateInput(menuSelection):

    if menuSelection in [1, 2, 3]:

        return True

    else:

        return False

def pcGenerate():

    pcChoice = random.randint(1,3)

    return pcChoice

# Calculate ties,wins,lose

def evaluateGame(playerChoice, pcChoice):

    rsp = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    win_statement = ['Rock breaks scissors', 'Paper covers rock', 'Scissors cut paper']

    win_status = (playerChoice - pcChoice) % 3

    print("You have chosen %s") % rsp[playerChoice - 1]

    what_to_say =("Computer has chose %s") % rsp[pcChoice - 1]

    if win_status == 0:

        what_to_say +=(" as Well. TIE!")

    elif win_status == 1:

        what_to_say +=(". %s. You WIN!") % win_statement[playerChoice - 1]

    else:

        what_to_say +=(". %s. You LOSE!") % win_statement[pcChoice - 1]

    print("what_to_say")

    return win_status

# Update track of ties, player wins, and computer wins
def updateScoreBoard(outcome, game_status):

    if outcome == 0:

        game_status.tie += 1

    elif outcome == 1:

        game_status.playerWon += 1

    else:

        game_status.pcWon += 1

# If user input is invalid, let them know.

def invalidChoice(menuSelect):

    print(menuSelect,("is not a valid option. Please select 1-3"))

# Print the scores before terminating the program.

def displayScoreBoard(game_status):
    print("")

    print("Statistics:")

    print(("Ties: %d") % game_status.tie)

    print(("Player Wins: %d") % game_status.playerWon)

    print(("Computer Wins: %d") % game_status.pcWon)

    if game_status.pcWon > 0:

        print("Win/Loss Ratio: %f") % (float(game_status.playerWon) / game_status.pcWon)

    else:

        print("Win/Loss Ratio: Always Win.")

    print("Rounds: %d") % game_status.get_round()

def endGameSelect(game_status):
    print("")

    print("[1]: Play again")

    print("[2]: Show Statistics")

    print("[3]: Save Game")

    print("[4]: Quit")

    print("")

    while True:

        menuselect = input("Enter your choice: ")

        if menuselect in [1, 2, 3, 4]:

            break

        else:

            print("Wrong input.")

    if menuselect == 2:

        displayScoreBoard(game_status)

        endGameSelect(game_status)

    elif menuselect == 3:

        f = open("%s.rsp" % game_status.name, 'w')

        pickle.dump(game_status, f)

        f.close()

        print("Your game is saved successfully.")

        endGameSelect(game_status)

    elif menuselect == 4:

        print("Bye!!!")

        exit()

main()
```

Comment: `input` retuns a `string`, try `if int(menuselect) in [1, 2, 3]:`

Comment: now it says a local variable 'game_status' referenced before assignment.

Comment: at that line, `welcomemenu` gets called, but hasn't been defined until later in the code.. to fix it move the `def main():` block of code down, place it above the last line of code, right before `main()`

Comment: now the problem is at the end of the program. the pickle.dump(game_status, f)    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: [Using pickle.dump - TypeError: must be str, not bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13906623/1248974), change the previous line to `f = open("%s.rsp" % game_status.name, 'wb')`. You should check other answers that already explain how to fix these type of errors

Comment: that worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you use input(), you get a string rather than an int.

You should change:

```
 menuselect = input("Enter your choice: ")
```

to this:

```
 menuselect = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
```

To get it as an integer, that way it will work with the rest of your script.

Comment: now the problem is at the end of the program. the pickle.dump(game_status, f) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not byte