# Not able to write the Count Vectorizer vocabulary

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

I want to save and load the count vectorizer vocabulary.This is my code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
Cv_vec = cv.fit(X['review'])
X_cv=Cv_vec.transform(X['review']).toarray()
dictionary_filepath='CV_dict'
pickle.dump(Cv_vec.vocabulary_, open(dictionary_filepath, 'w'))
```

It shows me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-407-3a9b06f969a9> in <module>()
      1 dictionary_filepath='CV_dict'
----> 2 pickle.dump(Cv_vec.vocabulary_, open(dictionary_filepath, 'w'))

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I want to save the vocabulary of the count vectorizer and load it.Can anyone help me with it please?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pickle.dump - TypeError: must be str, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906623/using-pickle-dump-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes)

Comment: try: `pickle.dump(Cv_vec.vocabulary_, open(dictionary_filepath, 'wb'))`

Comment: Thanks a lot.It was a minor error.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode when pickling out an object. And try to use a [context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), i.e.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
Cv_vec = cv.fit(X['review'])
X_cv=Cv_vec.transform(X['review']).toarray()
dictionary_filepath='CV_dict'

with open('CV_dict.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(Cv_vec.vocabulary_, fout)
```