# Self unpickling in class method in python

Tags: python, deserialization, self

I am trying to create an object which can serialize and deserialize itself with a class method, without using the return statement (I do not want a static method). This is a concept of my class and a naive use case:

```
import pickle

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def add(self):
        self.x += 1

    def serialize(self, filename):
        """Simple object serialization given a filename"""
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)
            print("Serialized with value of: %d" % (self.x))

    def deserialize(self, filename):
        """Simple object deserialization given a filename"""
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            print("self.x before load (inside deserialize): %d" % (self.x))
            self = pickle.load(f)
            print("Deserialized value inside deserialize function: %d" % (self.x))



a1 = A()
a2 = A()

a1.add()
a1.add()

a1.serialize('a.pkl')
a2.deserialize('a.pkl')

print("Deserialized value outside: %d" % (a2.x))
```

However, once I leave the deserialization method, `self` (in this case, the instance `a2`) does not keep its value.

Output when run:

```
>> Serialized with value of: 2
>> self.x before load (inside deserialize): 0
>> Deserialized value inside deserialize function: 2
>> Deserialized value outside: 0
```

Why is this happening? I have also tried with `deepcopy` just after the `pickle.load` in the function `deserialize` but nothing seems to work, and I would like to understand why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a few more functions to make this work. Otherwise you're just dumping the memory of the class constructor, not the instance of said class (if i'm not mistaken): https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances. A good explanation of the difference between a instance variable and a class variable can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842553/pickle-with-custom-classes

Comment: First of all please avoid `self = pickle.load(f)` and then in the `deserialize` method instead of outputting the read value, you are just asking it to print `self.x` which seems wrong to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pickle with custom classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842553/pickle-with-custom-classes)

Comment: @Torxed I have read it already, but his problem is that the empty variable is a class variable, not an instance variable. In my case, after the deserialization, the unchanged variable is an instance variable

Comment: That's because you don't call the appropriate built in functions `__update__` etc. That is, if you really don't want a return function as mentioned in the solution below.

Comment: @Torxed I cannot find anything related to `__update__`. Could you specify a reference, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that because you can't assign to self (or rather: doing that doesn't do what you think it does). If you're interested to find out what actually happens, try assigning something weird to `self`, e.g. `self = "foobar"` (the behaviour will be unchanged).

---

Make `deserialize` a classmethod and use it as a "constructor":

```
@classmethod
def deserialize(cls, filename):
    """Simple object deserialization given a filename"""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
        print("Deserialized value inside deserialize function: %d" % (obj.x))
        return obj
```

Then use it like this:

```
a2 = A.deserialize('a.pkl')
```

---

Output:

> Serialized with value of: 2
>   Deserialized value inside deserialize function: 2
>   Deserialized value outside: 2

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. I did not know I can't assign to `self`. Any reason or documentation on why this is not possible? Thanks!

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response.
Pickle flattens objects as dictionaries.
This is how to fix it:

```
    def serialize(self, filename):
        """Simple object serialization given a filename"""
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.__dict__, f)
            print("Serialized with value of: %d" % (self.x))

    def deserialize(self, filename):
        """Simple object deserialization given a filename"""
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            print("self.x before load (inside deserialize): %d" % (self.x))
            self.__dict__ = pickle.load(f)
            print("Deserialized value inside deserialize function: %d" % (self.x))
```