# Restoring old data to modified class

Tags: python

I have a python class which has been serialized in JSON.

```
import json

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ival = 45
        self.fval = 0.5
        self.str = 'A string'
       
    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'w') as dfile:
            jstr = json.dumps(self.__dict__)
            dfile.write(jstr)
    
    def load(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as dfile:
            jstr = dfile.read()
            jdict = json.loads(jstr)
            # Save what is currently there
            jsave = self.__dict__
            # Restore the old stuff
            self.__dict__ = jdict
            # Restore the original stuff
            for member in jsave.keys():
                if not member in jdict:
                    self.__dict__[member] = jsave[member]
    
    def scramble(self):
        self.ival = 99
        self.fval = 3.162
        self.str = 'another'

dfilename = './data.json'
dobj = Data()
dobj.save(dfilename)
```

Some time later, I add another value to the class

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.itwo = 2

...
dfilename = './data.json'
dobj = Data()
dobj.load(dfilename)
print(dobj.itwo)
```

This appears to work.

The question is, is this the best way of restoring a dictionary?  I wish to restore the values that were there but keep the ones that weren't there.  Is there a better way of merging dictionaries other than going through one key at a time as I have done?

Comment: Are you looking for `dict.update`?

Comment: Yes - dict.update is exactly what I'm looking for.  Really ought to read the docs.  Replaced the code with **self.__dict__.update(jdict)** and it works.  If you wish to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clobber the existing values in memory with what's in the file:

```
self.__dict__.update(jdict)
```

If you want to go the other way, there are a couple of simple options. Both start with

```
jdict.update(self.__dict__)
```

You can then swap references

```
self.__dict__ = jdict
```

Or copy values back:

```
self.__dict__.update(jdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way of course, but to achieve this with minimal efforts, you could use `setdefault()` method on a dict.

```py
self.__dict__[member] = jsave[member]
```

->

```py
self.__dict__.setdefault(member, jsave[member])
```

Regarding the better way: take a look at [**getstate** and **setstate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939058/simple-example-of-use-of-setstate-and-getstate) or at some high-level tools like [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/) or [Dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.update` or union `|`.

```
def load(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as dfile:
        jdict = json.load(dfile)
        jsave = self.__dict__
        self.__dict__ = jdict | jsave

        # self.__dict__ = jdict
        # self.__dict__.update(jsave)
```

Just a few other notes: Use `json.load` and `json.dump` when you can. `for key in jsave` is valid because you iterate over keys by default. Look into `setattr` as well.

Edit:
As [madbird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7183235/madbird) pointed out in the comments, if you're using something before Python 3.9, you will not be able to use the union operator. `dict.update` has been around in Python 2, but if you don't want to use the temporary assignment, you can use `{**jdict, **jsave}` as suggested by madbird.

Comment: Dicts union is not available in python versions prior to 3.8 iirc, so I could suggest to use in answers some older approach like `{**a, **b}`

Comment: Good point. I just looked it up, and it was [introduced in Python 3.9](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/). I should have considered the version. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using 3.7 but worth considering when I move to 3.9.