# Can't save list of objects in pickle

Tags: python, pickle

Here is how I save my object into a file:

```py
def save_to_file(file_path, user):
    # Writing to a file
        try:
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                user_list: list = pickle.load(file)
            user_list.append(user)
            with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
                pickle.dump(
                    [u for u in user_list], file
                )
        except:
            with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
                pickle.dump(
                    [user], file
                )
```

But whenever I want to use this code to log in it fails
The first saved object can easily login
But the other object in that file can't log in

```py
                try:
                    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                        user_list: list = pickle.load(f)

                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print("User does not Exists, Register first!")
                    return None
                print(user_list)
                for u in user_list:
                    if str(u.username) == username and str(u.get_password()) == password:
                        print("Login successful...")
```

Here is output when I print user_list:

```
[name : 1, username : 1, phone number : 1, email : No email!, name : 1, username : 1, phone number : 1, email : No email!, name : 2, username : 2, phone number : 2, email : No email!]
__repr__ overrided
```

Here is the class and I used **getstate** however I don't know if it's right or not
This line of my code is still False and if seems the `for` works just for once.

```
                for u in user_list:
                    if str(u.username) == username and str(u.get_password()) == password:
```

```
class User:
    """
    This class implements a user model
    that can login and register
    it dumps data to pickle file
    """

    def __init__(
            self, name: str, username: str, password: str, phone: str, balance: int, email: str = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.name: str = name
        self.username: str = username
        self.__password: str = password
        self.phone: str = phone
        self.balance: int = balance
        self.email: str = email

    def get_password(self) -> str:
        return self.__password

    def withdraw(self, amount) -> None:
        # self.balance - amount if self.balance > amount else print('Not Enough Balance Available')
        if self.balance > amount:
            self.balance -= amount
        else:
            print('Not Enough Balance Available')

    def deposit(self, amount) -> None:
        self.balance += amount

    def set_password(self, password) -> None:
        self.__password = password

    def show_balance(self) -> int:
        return self.balance

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d
```

Comment: Please post the error message as code. "It fails" doesn't give enough information to understand what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: Do not do `[u for u in user_list]`.  Just dump `user_list`, exactly like the way you loaded it.  it's already a list.

Comment: Does your `User` class implement the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939058/simple-example-of-use-of-setstate-and-getstate)?

Comment: @Barmar No I didn't use that

Comment: You probably should. See the linked question for the proper way to define a class so it can be pickled.

Comment: @Barmar Question edited. Still the same problem

Comment: @Barmar I've edited the code as you said but still I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining `__setstate__()` correctly. It receives a single argument, the dictionary that `__getstate__()` returned, not multiple arguments.

```
def __setstate(self, d):
    self.__dict__ = d
```

Comment: Edited the first post. I still get the same error

Comment: I guess I was wrong about what the problem is.

Comment: Any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know where that `__repr__ overrided` message is coming from or what it means.